$2^{\mathcal{O}(k)} \cdot n^{\mathcal{O}(1)}$ algorithm to break graphs $\mathcal{F}$ in $G$ with vertex deletion.
Let $G$ be any graph. Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote a set of graphs. We say that $G$ is $\mathcal{F}$ free if none of its subgraphs is isomorphic to a graph $f \in \mathcal{F}$. The problem is to delete at most $k$ vertices such that $G$ is $\mathcal{F}$ free. I know that we can find if $G$ is isomorphic to an $f \in \mathcal{F}$ in polynomial time. The problem has an FPT algorithm in $2^{\mathcal{O}(k)} \cdot n^{\mathcal{O}(1)}$ time, where $n=|V(G)|$. If $G$ has a subgraph isomorphic to $f$, then I know  that we need to delete a vertex in that subgraph to break the isomorphism. There are $|V(f)|$ many such vertices. So howcome is it that the branching vector is $2$ in the runtime ?

Is $\mathcal F$ fixed, or part of the input?

It is a part of the input. I got the problem from https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~malcin/book/parameterized-algorithms.pdf, It is exercise 3.7 (page 70)

In $2^{\mathcal O(k)}$, the branching factor is not actually specified: if all graphs in $\mathcal F$ have at most $v$ vertices, and you have a $v^k n^{\mathcal O(1)}$-time FPT algorithm, then you've solved the problem.
That's because $v^k = 2^{k \log_2 v}$, and $k \log_2 v$ is $\mathcal O(k)$. (The exercise you're solving specifically points out: Note that the constants hidden in the $\mathcal O()$-notation may depend on the set $\mathcal F$.)

Oh I was not expecting such a trick in the runtime like that, but now it all makes sense. Thanks

After seeing it a few times, you learn that $2^{\mathcal O(x)}$ is a very forgiving asymptotic estimate: it includes $\mathcal O(a^x)$ for any constant $a$.
